# PHP Mysqli HTML How to have current value from database selected in <select>

Tags: php, html, mysqli

my goal is get current value from database, selected in the dropdown list.
I tried that code but it shows always "Ndone" in the dropdownlist

```
<select name="work" id="work" value="<?php echo $work; ?>">
     <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
     <option selected="selected" value="DONE">DONE</option>
     <option selected="selected" value="NDONE">NDONE</option>
</select>
```

Also this one and nothing just the first row that selected in the dropdownlist

```
<select name="work" id="work" value="<?php echo $work; ?>">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="DONE">DONE</option>
     <option value="NDONE">NDONE</option>
</select>
```

I don't know what to do, any help please

When i use a textfield it works, so there's no problem with the variable `$work`

```
<input type="text" name="work" value="<?php echo $work; ?>"/>
```

Comment: Problem may be in your SQL, which isn't in your question, even some more PHP. Just dropdown code isn't enough to know for sure.

Comment: php works correctly because when i use a text field instead of dropdownlist, it shows the current value from database, no problem with that

Comment: Then see what the differences are between both and base yourself on that.

Comment: Why are all 3 options `selected="selected"`?

Comment: is $work what is set to either 'DONE or "NDONE"?

Comment: @Fred -ii- that's what i did but nothing :/ , i also tried other things but it doesn't work

Comment: Only one option should show `selected="selected"` you need to compare value in options with value from your database to determine which one that should be. There is no concept of `value` on a select element.

Comment: Just for fun, try to remove the `value="<?php echo $work; ?>"` from where you have it now and do `<option value="<?php echo $work; ?>"></option>` - just a hunch.

Comment: $work is a column from a table, and "Done" and "NDone" the two value of it

Comment: @Fred -ii- ok i'll try and we'll see

Comment: @Fred -ii- no it doesn't work

Comment: Try the answer below then.

Comment: it works finally @BreyndotEchse answer's work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<select>` does not have a "value" Attribute. You must add the `selected` attribute to **one** option.

```
<?php
$options = array(
    '',
    'DONE',
    'NDONE',
);
?>

<select name="work" id="work">
    <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option ?>"<?php echo $option === $work ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>><?php echo $option ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your example you could do this:

You just need to check each option value against the $work variable and if it matches add the selected attribute.

```
<select name="work" id="work">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="DONE" <?php echo($work == 'DONE'?'selected="selected"':''); ?>>DONE</option>
     <option value="NDONE" <?php echo($work == 'NDONE'?'selected="selected"':''); ?>>NDONE</option>
</select>
```

Comment: that doesn't work, it shows nothing, Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Sorry I had an error - see update - The second ? in the ternary operator should have been a :